# Are there other ways for co-editing with Word than OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive, privacy

For my company we would like to co-edit documents, but we don't like the privacy concerns about Microsoft OneDrive because it's hosted in the US.

Are there any other possibilities to use word together or is this "hardcoded" with OneDrive/SharePoint/Microsoft?

Comment: I believe simultaneous co-authoring is restricted to the MS cloud platforms. However, you should be able to share documents on DropBox or another cloud service. You just would not have AutoSave and one author would be blocked when another has the document open.

Comment: To avoid cloud-based OneDrive, you could host an [on-premises SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-server), then upload Microsoft Office documents to it for [collaboration and co-authoring](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/document-collaboration-and-co-authoring-ee1509b4-1f6e-401e-b04a-782d26f564a4).

Comment: Great idea @leeharvey1. Can you post your comment as an answer then I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid cloud-based OneDrive, you could host an on-premises **SharePoint Server**, then upload Microsoft Office documents to it for collaboration and co-authoring.

For more information, visit:

- SharePoint Server
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-server
- MS Office document collaboration and co-authoring
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/document-collaboration-and-co-authoring-ee1509b4-1f6e-401e-b04a-782d26f564a4